# How can i run nginx and node.js on one server?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

What kind of setup can i use to host both wordpress/php and node.js on the same server? I have a VPS from Digitalocean, an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I have read that some use: Apache -> Nginx -> Varnish, but then again i read some places that if you have Nginx you don’t need Varnish.

The solution i have now is Varnish on port 80 with 2 backends, one for Apache and one for Node.js.

Will this work for with nginx instead of Apache behind Varnish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your existing setup (Varnish front-end, with Apache & Node.js backends) will work the same if you switch Apache for Nginx (i.e. Varnish doesn't particularly care about the backends - Nginx and Apache will be treated the same).

Node.js is typically run with Nginx because it is much more efficient to serve static assets directly via Nginx than through Node.js. For a simple setup you can eliminate Varnish entirely - Node.js will run on port 80 and will proxy select requests to a Node.js upstream server:

```
upstream nodejs  {
      server 127.0.0.1:3000;
      server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name  www.example.com;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com/access.log;
        root   /var/www/www.example.com/public;

        location / {
             try_files $uri @nodejs;
        }

        location @nodejs {
             proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
             proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
             proxy_redirect off;
             proxy_buffering off;
             proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
             proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

One of the (previous) reasons for using Varnish in front of this setup was because Nginx did not natively support proxying HTTP 1.1 connections (which was needed for the Upgrade header used with Websockets) - this is no longer an issue, and current versions of Nginx are able to proxy websocket connections as well. That aside, if you are actually using Varnish to cache files that is a compelling reason to keep it as the front end server (although, it is worth noting that the only real gain occurs if you are using Varnish to serve cached copies of dynamically generated pages). For instance, if you have Nginx listening on port 81, and Node.js on port 3000, you might have the following in your Varnish VCL (which will serve paths from example.com/nodejs using Node.js and everything else with Nginx):

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "81";
}

backend nodejs{
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "3000";
}

...

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.grace = 120s;
    ...
    if (req.http.Host ~ "^(www\.)?example.com") {
        if (req.url ~ "^/nodejs/") {
            set req.backend = nodejs;                       
        }
    }

    return (lookup);
}
```

Comment: That varnish-setup is something like the one i have now. But when if i use Varnish, do i gain anything by having nginx before node.js? Or is it fine to only have varnish infront of node.js (and nginx).

Comment: That depends largely on your cache hit rate. If you have a high cache hit rate in Varnish, then in most cases Nginx will simply add an extra layer and make things appear a bit slower. If you have a low hit rate on static files, Nginx will make things faster (everything that misses the cache, has to be served from a backend server - and Nginx is significantly faster than Node.js); a low hit rate on dynamic files won't make that much of a difference, since Nginx would proxy back to Node.js anyway. If you are NOT caching your dynamic pages, you will probably find Nginx faster than Varnish.

Comment: By hit rate, do you mean how often the visitor will get a cache? My site(s) will probably be a small blog with some more or less static pages.

Comment: Hit rate in this context is referring to what percent of pages are loaded from cache (i.e. don't hit your backend servers). If your site generates static copies of pages (e.g. some blog plugins do that), then you will likely see better performance by eliminating Varnish from your setup and going with Nginx as your front end server and Node.js as a backend server. The advantage of Varnish is in its caching of dynamic pages (and the degree of control it offers over that caching).

Comment: Thank you for good answers, i think i understand some more now.